# Tic-tac-toe game graph design?

Tags: c++, oop, graph, tic-tac-toe

this is a general question from my homework, I am just asking for some ideas or pseudo code.
Suppose I am constructing a tic-tac-toe game using C++. What I already have is a `Node` class which contains a const member data represents the current game board state, and an const array of pointer to other Nodes that contains every possible next-step state. So this will be a directed graph with out duplicated nodes(every node has its unique game state.).

I got a trouble when I am trying to generate such a graph. It seems like I need to use recursion because all data members in `Node` class are const so there's no way to change them around. And I can hardly come up with a good idea to generate such a graph at once without Node duplicated(I mean it will be easy to make it a tree, but it waste lots of space and time.). One thing may help is I am able to compare two different game states, and I don't think I am allowed to use any templet other than `<set>`.

So if anyone got any idea about this, please free to write down your thought or pseudo code. Thank you

Comment: Java comes with a sample TicTacToe game.  Have you looked for example on the web?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes I looked around for hours but didn't find anything seems helpful to me..

Comment: If they need to be const, then you can only set them when you create them.  That means that you can only create a node after you have created all sub-nodes.

Comment: @SteveC yes that's true, I was just confused about how to implement it..

Comment: Wouldn't a tic tac toe game have few enough permutations that you could generate a 2 or 3 - depth tree for every move? There might be no need to pre-generate them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need is to check for existence:

```
std::set< Node > checked_node;

bool isNodeChecked( Node ){
    return checked_node.find( Node )!=checked_node.end();
}
```

You need to overload something like `operator =` and `operator <` for `std::set` to work on your `class Node`;

Also `std::unordered_map` might work.

( Although as it seems to me that a tic-tac-toe status can be represented by non-negative integers from 0 to 3^9. In this way a std::set would suffice but you need extra encode decode functions.